# Wix Bootstrapper doesn't support same version upgrade

Tags: bootstrapper

I have an wix bundle project which has a .NET 4.5 ExePackage and a MSI project. MSI project is a major upgrade with per-machine mode. When I run the wix bundle exe, it installs the MSI. But when I run the bundle exe second time (I don't uninstall the MSI before that, it still in Add/remove program list), it doesn't show MSI installation window even though I set MajorUpgrade as below.

I find the log of bundle that it detected the installed MSI version at second time and doesn't invoke MSI anymore.

Detected package: **SetupMSI**, state: Present, cached: Complete
...
Planned package: **SetupMSI**, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register

Is there a way to modify the bundle file to let it run MSI even if it detected an installed package?

Comment: I found the reason that it caused by bundle theme in which some modified the <Page Name="Modify"> section themes.